# seaborn/matplotlib: showing different tick ranges in one plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I created a Boxplot like this:

```
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,7))
sns.despine(bottom=True, left=True)

sns.boxplot(x=x)
ax.set(xlim=(0, 120))
ax.grid(linestyle='-', axis="x")
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(24))
ax.set_axisbelow(True)
plt.show()
```

Which look like this:

[image]

Like i already marked in the Picture, i want a different xtick range for a specific part in the graph. So until the value of 24 the ticker should be `ticker.MultipleLocator(8)` and then it should continue with `ticker.MultipleLocator(24)`.

Comment: I understand that I can't combine MultipleLocators, so how about creating and setting up scales for less than 24 and more than 24?`tickA=np.arange(0,24,8);tickB=np.arange(24,120,24);new_ticks = np.concatenate([tickA, tickB]);ax.set_xticks(new_ticks)`

Comment: @r-beginners this works for me, thanks! Maybe you can post this solution in an answer (?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since multiple locators cannot be mixed, there is a way to create and combine scales for each.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,7))
sns.despine(bottom=True, left=True)

g = sns.boxplot(x=tips['total_bill'])
ax.set(xlim=(0, 120))
ax.grid(linestyle='-', axis="x")

tickA = np.arange(0,24,8)
tickB = np.arange(24,120,24)
new_ticks = np.concatenate([tickA, tickB])
ax.set_xticks(new_ticks)

ax.set_axisbelow(True)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: @smytech Thank you for giving me the opportunity to answer.